# MySQL prepared statements syntax

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, statements

If we want to use prepared statements for MySQL queries, we write something like this:

```
"INSERT INTO users set email=?, pass=?", [$email,$pass]
```

this is fine if there are few vars (1-5), but if there are many vars (10 or more), we may confuse the order of vars or miss some of them. Is there SQL syntax with associations, something like this:

```
"INSERT INTO users set email=(?email), pass=(?pass)", ['email'=>$email,'pass'=>$pass]
```

I am using Laravel 4 php framework.

Comment: What programming language and database layer are you preparing the statements in? The notation varies considerably from one driver to another.

Comment: I am using Laravel 4 php framework.

Comment: Try to use the [Laravel Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries) whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it, it's:

```
"INSERT INTO users set email=:email, pass=:pass", ['email'=>$email,'pass'=>$pass]
```

and it should be save query (SQL injectionс-proof), correct me if I'm wrong.